# Save canvas with external images to local file

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to save to the local filesystem a canvas with loaded images from external websites into it?

If I try with toDataUrl(), it just trhows a Security error. In Firefox I can just save to a file the canvas with the right click, but this is not possible in Chrome.

Comment: Show us the code. In principle canvas can be exported to png/jpeg/bmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for security reasons you can't use `toDataUrl()`.

For why this is happening you need to look into [cors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

[Here's a bit on why it should be this way](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules).

It's a feature in Firefox that you can right-click save-as because its all local. If it were with `toDataUrl()` then the webpage could also attempt to send the canvas data to the server and we don't want that.

The right-click save-as is a requested feature in Opera and may come to other browsers someday but I wouldn't bank on the functionality existing any time soon.