# HTML5/JS - Hitting an error while exporting canvas to PNG - images from other severs

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have made Catifier.com recently, and once the user sets their own background image, you can no longer export the canvas, do it built in safety precautions.

I have been trying for a few days to get another way to save, but just can't find anything.

Does anyone know of a totally different way to export the canvas as an image without using toDataURL?

Any help or links would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you not just run the external images through a thumbnail script on your domain (taking suitable precautions against DOS attacks) and hence bypass this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just run the external images through a script on your domain (taking suitable precautions against DOS attacks) and hence bypass this issue? Otherwise I think the answer is most probably no (and if this was not the case, it would probably be counted as a browser bug; see: http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules etc). The server-side solution should however be viable.

Also see: [Save canvas with external images to local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656521/save-canvas-with-external-images-to-local-file)